# Java, Spring best practices to use variables in properties files

Tags: java, spring, file, ant, properties

I use org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.
There are 3 properties files. So if properties duplicate - last wins.

The first file contains all properties, others substitute some properties.
I use e.g. variable like

```
log.dir=c:/log.
```

So I can substitute part of path in properties like

```
${log.dir}/app1.log
```

In first file I have 48 uses of this variable.

In second file I have 25 substitutes for properties from first file, and 5 substitutes in third file.

The problem that I need redefine this variable also in second and third file!

I would like use the same name

```
log.dir
```

But if I define it in second or third file - redefining go back to first file - but I need  use for the rest 18 (48 -25 - 5=18) old properties.
What the best practices in similar cases?
Thanks.
After some analysis I would like have variable that has the same name in all properties files, but values must not be overridden. So for first file  log.dir=c:\log, for the second  log.dir=d:\log, for the third  log.dir=e:\log. And when calculating paths for each file used own. So overridden must be only properties - not variables.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you said. In any case, you may want to look into writing a customized placeholder configurator, although it sounds like you're abusing the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What (I think) you'd like to do is to make the `log.dir` variable changing the value as the configurer steps through the property files and encounters your overriding definitions.

The problem is, the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` does not work this way; for every encountered `${placeholder}` definition it checks only **the winning** redefinition. It does resolve placeholders taking into account the context of the file they're defined in.

I see only one feasible solution: use a different variable name in each file. Writing your own placeholder configurator is probably very poor gain-to-workload ratio.